# Message level secutiy with SSL in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, certificate, message

I am trying to use WCF to design web service over internet. The requirement is that we need to
provide the TLS (Transport Layer Security) and MLS (Message Layer Security). For this purpose, we are using "**ws2007HttpBinding**" with security mode as "**TransportWithMessageCredential**". Here, I find that the request is transferred over SSL but when using Fiddler (for https) I find that the soap body is in clear text format.

For the transport level security, I have used ClientCredentialType as "None" and for message level security, I have used "Certificate" as ClientCredentialType.

I am using .net framework 3.5.

For your information, I am using different certificate for SSL & server.

My Web.config for Server is as follows.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="API_WCF.Service1Behavior" name="API_WCF.API">
            <endpoint address="https://localhost/API_WCF/API.svc" name="API" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customWsHttpBinding" contract="API_WCF.IARDAPI">
                <identity>
                    <dns />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <ws2007HttpBinding>
            <binding name="customWsHttpBinding">
      <!-- For http  -->
      <!--
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
      </security>
      -->
      <!-- For https  -->
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="API_WCF.Service1Behavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://localhost/API_WCF/API.svc/API"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=WSE2QuickStartServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeName="My"/>
                    <clientCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                    </clientCertificate>
                </serviceCredentials>

                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true" performanceCounters="ServiceOnly">
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Kindly guide how to achieve to message level security with transport layer security in WCF over internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run fiddler in HTTPS mode to view your WCF messages, then you are already using TLS!

If the messages are encrypted while using fiddler in HTTP mode this indicates that your messages are being secured before being sent over the wire. See: [How to: Use Transport Security and Message Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms789011.aspx)

The use of TransportWithMessageCredential means that in a HTTP scenario your service will be protected through HTTPS and you can opt to have an additional in-message credential(MLS).

Answer (score 0):

If you want SSL and message level encryption (rather than just message level authentication) then you need to use a custom binding. For example (actual config depends on what you want):

```
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
<security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"></security>
<httpsTransport />
```

Comment: When I am trying to use the above suggested solution I am getting the following error. System.InvalidOperationException: Security policy export failed. The binding contains both a SymmetricSecurityBindingElement and a secure transport binding element. Policy export for such a binding is not supported.

Comment: please create first a binding with just message security (no ssl) which suits your needs. Then publish it and we will see how to add ssl to it.

Comment: also if you get another exception specify when you get it (when adding wsdl reference, creating the proxy, getting response etc)

Comment: I am able to create a binding with just message security, now can you guide me how to go about setting it up on SSL?

Comment: if you just change to https, at which stage do you get the exception

Comment: When I try to browse the web service (svc) and try to access the wsdl. at that time, I am getting the policy export error.

Comment: Not sure why wcf gives this error. Anyhow the error says it cannot generate WSDL for this dual protection mode, but it does not say this protection mode is not supported. I suggest you remove the SSL setting, then generate the client with "add service reference", and then configure separately both client and server to use httpsTransport. This way you bypass the wsdl generation part (maybe it will even be required to remove the mex endpoint and disallow the server to generate metadata)

Comment: Hi Yaron, Thanks for your suggestion. it works for this problem but I have certain questions for this approach. 1) When our web service will be consumed by multiple clients, especially clients may join service whenever they want kind of scenario. How WSDL can be shared with them? (in case metadata is not available) 2) we tested web service for .net 3.5, 4.0 & 4.5 framework but found that the security policy export exception does not appear in case of .net 4.0 & 4.5. It comes with .net 3.5 (Unfortunately, I am supposed to use this only). Then any idea about fix on this issue in .net 3.5.

Comment: Also, 3) as you have mentioned in your solution, messageVersion is mentioned as "Soap11", which means that soap version 1.1 will be supported by Web Service but how to enable it for soap 1.1 & soap 1.2 also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create multiple endpoints for this service, one with soap11 and one with soap12. If you need a WSDL then you can use a hard coded WSDL. You may even strip the policy out of the WSDL you got when omitted the https and publish it.